# how do I get the size of the file before upload using Selenium

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I've been trying for days to do this..

I want to simply get the size of the file before it is uploaded.

something like this:

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("FileUpload"));
string fileSizeInKB = element.GetAttribute("files[0].size");
```

or this:

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("FileUpload"));
string fileSizeInKB = element.GetAttribute("files")[0].size;
```

neither of these ways works so I'm asking how I could archive something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the System.IO.File namespace

```
byte[] buffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"yourfilename");
int size = buffer.Length;
```

Update

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
string title = (string)js.ExecuteScript("Your JavaScript Here");
```

Comment: but that would get the file size of the file in the file system not the file size reported by the client in the browser. they are incidentally the same in this case but you could imagine various scenarios where this could be different.

Comment: the value I specifically want to target is this one in Javascript: this.files[0].size

Comment: then you can use IJavaScriptExecutor to execute the javascript.

Comment: Thank you so much :) that IJavaScriptExecutor works like a dream :)

you should edit your answer and include both methods in your answer for others to see :)

Comment: @Helbo - Cheers !